# Setting Column width in jQuery Datatables using aoColumnDefs

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I use Datatables to display dynamic data from my database via ajax. Because the user can filter the data, not all the possible columns are always displayed. I wanted to set the width of certain columns so decided to use `aTargets` within the header data, and then used `aoColumnDefs` to pick out certain columns and change the width. For some reason this doesn't work.

You can see my code below, I am getting the json data via ajax and re-creating the datatable each time using `"bDestroy": true,`

**Table Headers JSON:**

```
[{"sTitle":"Category","aTargets":[0]},{"sTitle":"Tag Title","aTargets":[1]},{"sTitle":"Question","aTargets":[2]},{"sTitle":"Date\/Time","aTargets":[3]},{"sTitle":"Score","aTargets":[4]},{"sTitle":"Comment","aTargets":[5]},{"sTitle":"First Node","aTargets":[6]},{"sTitle":"Second Node","aTargets":[7]},{"sTitle":"Thrid Node","aTargets":[8]},{"sTitle":"Forth Node","aTargets":[9]},{"sTitle":"Fifth Node","aTargets":[10]},{"sTitle":"Sixth Node","aTargets":["data_analysis_category"]}]
```

As you can see the `Sixth Node` header at the end has an `aTargets` of "data_analysis_category"

**Javascript:**

```
    var res = $('#export_table').dataTable({

        "bDestroy": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<""f>t<"F"lp>',
        "aoColumns": pp['headers'],
        "aaData": pp['data'],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
                      { "sWidth": "200px", "aTargets": ["data_analysis_category"]}
                  ],
    })
```

As you can see I am trying to target "data_analysis_category" within the `aoColumnDefs` and set the width, but it does absolutely nothing.

I have been trying to get this working for quite some time without luck, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the classname for that last column `dataColumnDefs` (A string in aTargets only targets classnames)? You could try setting `sClass` in the json response for your last column.

Comment: @LouisHuppenbauer I just made the following amendment to the last column `{"sTitle":"Sixth Node","aTargets":["data_analysis_category"],"sClass":"data_analysis_category"}` and I have a class called `data_analysis_category` with `width: 200px` but still nothing is happening.